Cover photo is not displaying from another ui
So I have a flutter app where on one page I add the cover photo of the program user tries to create and I want to display that cover photo on his profile, I will leave here video to understand the issue better: https://imgur.com/a/u2Lz6IJ .
Here it's the page where user upload cover photo by using button 'Edit' and add it to storage :
class _WorkoutContentAddedState extends State<WorkoutContentAdded> {
  String? coverPhotoUrl;
  File? _image;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadCoverPhotoUrl();
  }

  Future<void> _loadCoverPhotoUrl() async {
    try {
      final docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('programs').doc('your_program_id');
      final docSnapshot = await docRef.get();

      if (docSnapshot.exists) {
        final data = docSnapshot.data();
        if (data != null && data.containsKey('coverPhotoUrl')) {
          setState(() {
            coverPhotoUrl = data['coverPhotoUrl'] as String?;
          });
          print('Loaded cover photo URL: $coverPhotoUrl');
        } else {
          print('No cover photo URL found in Firestore document');
        }
      } else {
        print('Document does not exist. Creating a new one.');
        await docRef.set({
          'createdAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          // Add any other initial fields you want for a new program
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error loading cover photo URL: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('programs').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
          }

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }

          if (snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
            return Center(child: Text('No programs available'));
          }

          DocumentSnapshot firstDocument = snapshot.data!.docs.first;
          Map<String, dynamic> firstData = firstDocument.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

          return CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverAppBar(
                expandedHeight: 300,
                floating: false,
                pinned: true,
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  background: Stack(
                    fit: StackFit.expand,
                    children: [
                      if (coverPhotoUrl != null && coverPhotoUrl!.startsWith('http'))
                        Image.network(
                          coverPhotoUrl!,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                            print('Error loading image: $error');
                            return Image.asset(
                              'assets/cover_photo.jpg',
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            );
                          },
                        )
                      else if (_image != null)
                        Image.file(
                          _image!,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        )
                      else
                        Image.asset(
                          'assets/cover_photo.jpg',
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      Positioned(
                        left: 16,
                        right: 16,
                        bottom: 16,
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              firstData['title'] ?? 'No title',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 24,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 8),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 6),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                  ),
                                  child: Text(
                                    firstData['category'] ?? 'N/A',
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: 8),
                                Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 6),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                  ),
                                  child: Text(
                                    (firstData['days'] as List<dynamic>?)?.map((day) => day.toString()[0].toUpperCase()).join(' ') ?? 'N/A',
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                leading: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white),
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                actions: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                      onPressed: _showBottomSheet,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.edit, color: Colors.white),
                      label: Text('Edit', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showBottomSheet() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20)),
      ),
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
          ),
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    print("Add cover photo button pressed");
                    _pickImage();
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Add cover photo',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 12),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                    ),
                    elevation: 5,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 24),
                Text(
                  'Add more details about the workout',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16),
                Text(
                  'Do you use any equipment for the workouts?',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16),
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'eg: 2kg dumbbells, 3kg ball',
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 24),
                Center(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      // TODO: Implement save functionality
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Save',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                      foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32, vertical: 16),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> _pickImage() async {
    print("_pickImage method started");
    try {
      final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
      print("Attempting to pick an image");
      final XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

      if (image != null) {
        print("Image picked: ${image.path}");
        setState(() {
          _image = File(image.path);
          // Don't set coverPhotoUrl here
        });

        // Upload the image and update Firestore
        await _uploadImage();

        // Show a success message
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(content: Text('Cover photo updated successfully')),
            );
          } else {
            print('No image selected');
          }
        } catch (e) {
          print('Error picking image: $e');
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(content: Text('Error selecting image: $e')),
          );
        }
      }
    
      Future<void> _uploadImage() async {
        if (_image == null) return;
    
        try {
          print('Starting image upload process');
          final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
          final imageRef = storageRef.child('program_covers/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.jpg');
          
          print('Uploading to path: ${imageRef.fullPath}');
    
          final uploadTask = imageRef.putFile(_image!);
          final snapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() => print('Upload completed'));
          
          final downloadURL = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
          print('Download URL obtained: $downloadURL');
    
          // Check if the document exists, if not, create it
          final docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('programs').doc('your_program_id');
          final docSnapshot = await docRef.get();
    
          if (docSnapshot.exists) {
            await docRef.update({
              'coverPhotoUrl': downloadURL,
            });
          } else {
            await docRef.set({
              'coverPhotoUrl': downloadURL,
              // Add any other initial fields you want for a new program
              'createdAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            });
          }
    
          print('Image uploaded and Firestore updated');
          setState(() {
            coverPhotoUrl = downloadURL;
          });
    
          // Reload the cover photo URL to ensure UI is updated
          await _loadCoverPhotoUrl();
    
        } catch (e) {
          print('Error in _uploadImage: $e');
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(content: Text('Error uploading image: $e')),
          );
        }
      }
    }

And here is where I try to display the cover photo again on MyProfileScreen()
 class _MyProfileScreenState extends State<MyProfileScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  // ... existing code ...

  String? coverPhotoUrl;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
    _loadCoverPhotoUrl();
  }

  Future<void> _loadCoverPhotoUrl() async {
    final programDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('programs').limit(1).get();
    if (programDoc.docs.isNotEmpty) {
      final programData = programDoc.docs.first.data();
      final coverPhotoPath = programData['coverPhotoPath'] as String?;
      if (coverPhotoPath != null) {
        try {
          final url = await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(coverPhotoPath).getDownloadURL();
          setState(() {
            coverPhotoUrl = url;
          });
        } catch (e) {
          print('Error loading cover photo: $e');
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ... existing code ...

    return Scaffold(
      // ... existing code ...
      body: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        future: _getUserData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          // ... existing code ...

          return Column(
            children: [
              // ... existing code ...
              Expanded(
                child: TabBarView(
                  controller: _tabController,
                  children: [
                    // Workout Tab Content
                    StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('programs').snapshots(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                        }
                        if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
                        }
                        if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
                          return Center(
                            child: Text(
                              'There is no workout content posted yet',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16,
                                color: Colors.grey[600],
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                        
                        // Display the first workout program
                        var program = snapshot.data!.docs.first;
                        var programData = program.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                        
                        return Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Stack(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  if (coverPhotoUrl != null)
                                    Image.network(
                                      coverPhotoUrl!,
                                      width: double.infinity,
                                      height: 200,
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                                        print('Error displaying image: $error');
                                        return Image.asset(
                                          'assets/cover_photo.jpg',
                                          width: double.infinity,
                                          height: 200,
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        );
                                      },
                                    )
                                  else
                                    Image.asset(
                                      'assets/cover_photo.jpg',
                                      width: double.infinity,
                                      height: 200,
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    ),
                                  Container(
                                    width: double.infinity,
                                    height: 200,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                                        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                                        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                        colors: [
                                          Colors.transparent,
                                          Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
                                        ],
                                        stops: [0.5, 1.0],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Positioned(
                                    left: 16,
                                    right: 16,
                                    bottom: 16,
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          programData['title'] ?? 'Untitled Program',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 20,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(height: 8),
                                        ElevatedButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            Navigator.push(
                                              context,
                                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WorkoutContentAdded()),
                                            );
                                          },
                                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                            foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                            ),
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
                                          ),
                                          child: Text(
                                            'View Programs',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 16,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                    // ... Diet Tab Content ...
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  // ... rest of the existing code ...
}

